# Viewing what posts link to your posts

Tags: support, hyperlinks

Is there a way to see what Stack Overflow posts link to your questions and answers? Such as posts reported as duplicates of one of your questions, comments that direct someone to one of your posts, etc., kind of like external links for websites, except only internal to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Visit one of your posts, in the right-side bar, under heading: Linked.

Comment: @rene unfortunately, this only works for questions, not answers. So, you can't know if somebody linked to an answer of yours or just to the question you've answered. Similarly, you can't tell if somebody linked your question specifically or an answer under the question.

Comment: Here is a SEDE query that is the best you can get: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1125068/answers-that-are-linked-by-their-parent-post Otherwise you need to 'scrape' / parse all bodies and all comments and that won't fly on SEDE as it would take longer then 2 minutes